# Redeployment in Kubernetes does not scale down the old Replica set

Tags: kubernetes

When we are trying to redeploy the same deployment which is already running, Deployment does not do the rolling update on the replicasets which means old and new replica sets are running.

I have tried to set the `revisionHistoryLimit` to 1 but it also does not help. Everytime, I am trying to delete/scale down the old replicaset by

```
kubectl delete replicaset/<old_replciaset_name> -n <namespace>
```

or

```
kubectl scale replicaset/<old_replciaset_name> --replicas=0
```

Comment: What does your deployment look like? Can you include the manifest?

Comment: What is your initial deploying kubectl command looks like? and what is the command you are using when redeploying?

Comment: did you try to delete with --force and --grace-period=0? also try to describe the object maybe you can have more information